# How to add options in xbbg API BDP for Bloomberg

Tags: python, bloomberg

In BDP in Excel, I can get 'CBBT, 'BVAL' and can't get 'BMMK'.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOHOy.png)

ex) CBBT

```
@BDP("EI3229347 Corp", "PX_CLEAN_MID", "PCS", "CBBT")  
@BDP("EI3229347 Corp", "YLD_YTM_MID", "PCS", "CBBT")  
@BDP("EI3229347 Corp", "INT_ACC", "SETTLE_DT", "20221230")  
@BDP("EI3229347 Corp", "DUR_MID", "PCS", "CBBT", "SETTLE_DT", "20221230")  
@BDP("EI3229347 Corp", "DUR_ADJ_MID", "PCS", "CBBT", "SETTLE_DT", "20221230")  
@BDP("EI3229347 Corp", "DUR_ADJ_OAS_MID", "PCS", "CBBT", "SETTLE_DT", "20221230")  
@BDP("EI3229347 Corp", "CNVX_MID", "PCS", "CBBT", "SETTLE_DT", "20221230")
```

I have the following code:

```
from xbbg import blp

ticker = 'EI3229347 Corp'
fields = [
    'PX_CLEAN_MID'
    , 'YLD_YTM_MID'
    , 'INT_ACC'
    , 'DUR_MID'
    , 'DUR_ADJ_MID'
    , 'DUR_ADJ_OAS_MID'
    , 'CNVX_MID'
]
std_date = '20221230'
# PCS = ['CBBT', 'BMRK', 'BVAL']

df = blp.bdp(
    tickers=ticker
    , flds=fields
    , SETTLE_DT=std_date
)

print(df)
```

It seems to be result in 'CBBT'

which works just fine.

but I hope to get separately 'CBBT, 'BVAL','BMMK'.

```
from xbbg import blp

ticker = 'EI3229347 Corp'
fields = [
    'PX_CLEAN_MID'
    , 'YLD_YTM_MID'
    , 'INT_ACC'
    , 'DUR_MID'
    , 'DUR_ADJ_MID'
    , 'DUR_ADJ_OAS_MID'
    , 'CNVX_MID'
]
std_date = '20221230'
PCS = ['CBBT', 'BMRK', 'BVAL']

for p in PCS:
    df = blp.bdp(
        tickers=ticker
        , flds=fields
        , SETTLE_DT=std_date
        , PCS=p
    )

    print(df)
```

It doesn't work, can anybody help me with this

Like Excel, I hope to get 'CBBT, 'BVAL'. How to solve 'PCS'?

Comment: Hervé you tried with TICKER@BVAL Corp?

Comment: how?? Do you teach me examples?

Comment: `ticker = 'EI3229347@BVAL Corp'`

Comment: I'm using in python. Is it how to Excel?

Comment: That works in Excel, not sure about Python. Maybe 'EI3229347 BVAL Corp'. You can check other similar questions, you may find something. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbloomberg%5D+price+source